# How the staking on stellar website works

Tags: xlm, lumens

Can someone please explain to me how the staking works? I've just stake some stellar on their website and they are gone from my wallet without any confirmation email or something and without knowing for how long and so on...

Am I able to see them somewhere or any proof that I stake them?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to "stake" Stellar Lumens. It looks like you've been scammed.

Comment: yes...100k lumens...